# Random coupon code, make sure they're all unique

Tags: php, arrays, string, methods

My code:

```
echo "<table width='200px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'><tbody>";

$total = 500;
for ($j = 0; $j < $total;$j++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . ($j+1) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . get_coupon_code() . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

function get_coupon_code() {
    $characters = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUZWXYZ';
    $random_string_length = 8;
    $string = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $random_string_length; $i++) {
        $string .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $string;
}

echo "</tbody></table>";
```

What would be the way to ensure that each code that's generated is unique?

Comment: By checking the previously generated codes.

Comment: Store the coupons in DB (for example) and keep generating them in do..while loop as long as you hit the code that is saved in DB.

Comment: Hilarious, PeeHaa. vojtek, I'd rather not store anything in the database, but would rather check against an array or something.

Comment: @dcolumbus 1. I never said anything about a database. 2. It didn't really think it was hilarious. 3. You are generating somewhat random codes how else do you expect them to be 100% sure unique if you don't compare them?

Comment: PeeHaa, if you could see above, you'd notice that the database comment was pointed at "vojtek" ... and it's not exactly unheard of that one would want UNIQUE strings. My questions IS asking how to ensure that each code is unique ... which means comparing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use static array variable to store your coupon codes and before returning the code ensure that it is not available in the array. Or more simpler, store the codes in an array handled in a session.

```
function get_coupon_code() {
$arr = $_SESSION['codes'];
    $characters = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUZWXYZ';
    $random_string_length = 8;
    $string = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $random_string_length; $i++) {
        $string .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
if (is_array($arr) && in_array($string, $arr))
{
return get_coupon_code();
}
else{
$_SESSION['codes'][] = $string;
    return $string;
}
}
```

**Edited** adding return to inner call of get_coupon_code()

Comment: Could you write a little bit of sample code? Specifically the comparing.

Comment: I was thinking of using `in_array`, but I'm not sure how you feel about that?

Comment: Don't know if it matters to you, but the solution of keeping them in a static array will not survive a server restart. That is, any time the PHP service restarts, the array will be re-initialized to an empty array.

Comment: Actually, the coupon codes will vary from visitor to visitor, and be lost with each session. If you're trying do anything meaningful or intelligent with the coupons aside from give people a random 8 character string, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: This would be unique per client and session lifetime.. Not even close to unique

Comment: From the HTML code I understand that, it is way to generate code to be printed locally.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then, if he's just going to run this once and print it out for whatever ends.

Answer (score 1):

The only true way to make sure you don't duplicate codes is to save them into a database, a file, or to keep them in memory (if the duration is short).

You might also want to check out PHP's `uniqid()` function:

```
print_r( uniqid() );

// Sample output:
//
// 50c65cefe58b1
```

But this might not meet your solution, since (a) it's still not guaranteed to be entirely unique, and (b) it introduces numbers to the code (not just letters).

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Yeah, I need only letters and specific ones at that.

Comment: Watch out, `uniqid` is *deterministic*.  While you're going to be OK using it for coupon codes, it should never be used where security needs to be worried about.